# Get element by ID at particular html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the same element:

```
<div id="demo_div" style="display:none;"></div>
```

on both **page1.html** and **page2.html**.

The JavaScript has access both to page1.html and page2.html. When I access element with

```
$("#demo_div")
```

I get element that is the *first* in the DOM (page1.html and page2.html are tabs of index.html, so one of them is hidden but always exist in the DOM).

Is that possible to get the element from a particular page?

**UPDATE 1**:

The entire HTML:

```
<html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Index Page</title>

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="modules/page1.js?version=5"></script>
    <script src="modules/page2.js?version=5"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content" style="display:none;">
    <div id="main_tabs">
        <ul id="tabs_header">
            <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="modules/page1.html?version=3">Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="modules/page2.html?version=14">Page2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I can't have unique IDs because I use `.load` for loading page2.html as hidden part of page1.html thus I will have duplicate elements.

**UPDATE 3**:

I run the JavaScript from within a `.js` file that is linked to index.html so it has access to its siblings (page1.html and page2.html).

Comment: Can we have your entire html ?

Comment: ID's should be unique, also when using two files together to create a DOM structure, but if each page has a parent element, like `#page1` etc. you can always just do `$('#demo_div', '#page2');`

Comment: **IDs must be unique in the DOM**. That's the rules. Play by them and it gets easier. Also, you could try `window.location`, e.g. `if (window.location.pathname === 'page1.html') { alert("we're on page 1"); }`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: What do you mean by "The JS has access both to page1.html and page2.html."? How do you run the JS?

Comment: Don't use the same 'ID' for more than one element on the same page. PERIOD.

Comment: @MichaelZ I still don't understand why you must have duplicate IDs. Use the class attribute instead!

Comment: @PetrPeller See UPDATE 3

Comment: @OllyHodgson And what will be a different? I will get the first element at the DOM that has some class : $(".myClass") but I need element on particular page but not the first!

Comment: If you can't have unique ID's then don't use them, because they won't work if they're not unique. If you use a class, then something like `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array of elements, and you can pick the one you want.

Comment: So put a unique id on a parent element in each page, e.g. `<div id="page1">`, `<div id="page2">`. Then use e.g. `$("#page2 .demo_div")` to find it.

Comment: Are you saying you can't have unique ID's based on the fact that you are including one file inside another? Jeezes, just change the HTML in one file to classes or unique ID's.

Comment: @OllyHodgson But how can I do this? I have the IDENTICAL divs because I use _load_ here!

Comment: Why can't you change the id of the element you are loading? Do you not have access to the file you are loading, as in it is being served by a third party? Even if you are using load, you should be able to load/generate different content.

Comment: @MichaelZ Are you saying you can't change the html of `page1.html` and `page2.html`? Or perhaps `.load()` them into `<div id="page1">`?

Comment: Do you know what page you're loading? Then just add a class to the div:  $('myDiv').addClass('page' + thePageNr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone missed it. The problem can be solved using dynamically added classes when you know what page is loading. Just add a class to the div:

```
$('myDiv').addClass('page' + thePageNr);
```

Nevertheless: Remove the duplicate IDs, they will produce unexpected behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

Dom element ID should be unique!. But in your case it is not.

If you still like to go with same id, then try using below with [**attribute selector**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), but usually no one will recommend having same ids

```
 $("div[id='demo_div']")
```